# Not able to access the webservice available in same network in Android

Tags: android, sockets, httpclient, terminal-emulator

I am using Android 2.1 tablet. I have created simple application which access my own webservice. It works well in emulator. But it fails on android device. I am getting timeout exception. I have internet permission and timeout permission as mentioned is few forum message. I have disabled firewall for my network. Though I couldn't ping it from Terminal emulator to check the network availability. 
Also I tried access the webservice base url via browser in android device. It doesn't work. I have webservice running on port 9080 in a laptop which is connected to same wifi network as android device. 
I am absolute clueless. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The fact that you can't ping it sounds like there is a problem.  Any details on the network configuration.  DHCP, etc?

Answer (score 0):

If the emulator was running on the same machine as the Web service, then perhaps your Web service is only accepting connections from `localhost`.